# Android ScrollView fading edge works on emulator but not on my phone

Tags: android, scrollview, emulation

When testing the code below on various emulators provided by the ADT it works exactly how it should.  However, when pushing the same exact build to my phone, my phone does not perform the fading edge feature.  Everything else works normally.  Has anyone experienced this before?

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android v4.3.   I have tested this on emulators using v4.2.2 and 4.4 (as well as some others).

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionscroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="50dp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical" >
```

**EDIT**

I've sent this build to my friend and his Samsung Galaxy S3 running v4.3 does not see the fading edge either.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm setOverScroll Mode?

Samsung stated messing with this in gingerbread

Right  now, you are probably seeing only 1 to 2px of the fadding edge. if you set the setOverScroll than that should fix it probably. OVER_SCROLL_NEVER

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried to add that call to setOverScrollMode to OVER_SCROLL_NEVER, but I didn't see any changes.

Comment: I can also confirm this does not solve the problem. Still looking for a solution.